# How to merge two column from different tables in mySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables one for lets take A table it has one column called 'id' and it has row values like 1,2,3,4,5. and B table has column 'id' and it has row values like 3,4
and I want to display the output like only 1,2,5,6.  DO Not use in/not/exists in

Table A

id

1

2

3

4

5

Table B

id

3

4

6

output:

id

1

2

5

6

Comment: Is this a homework task? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
select id from (
select id from A
union
select id from B
) tmp
where id = 1 or id = 2 or id = 5 or id = 6
```